# "Displays" setting not accessible after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, 17.04

"Dispalay" option don't exits in "System settings" after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.04. Help ... ?

[image]

Comment: How did you upgrade 16.04 to 17.04?

Comment: With update-manager

Comment: You can't directly upgrade skipping a release. Something went wrong. And it was a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Its my home laptop. I don't remember, maybe it was 16.10. I did what I was always doing starting with version 11.xx. There were some issues but minor one. This time everything is wrong

Comment: If you've been release upgrading since 2011 perhaps now is a good time to backup and install fresh.

Comment: Yep. Its what i have done. Installed fresh.